# Photoshoot in Durdle Door and Lulworth Cove

Tags: uk, legal, photography, weddings

I was wondering if someone knows whether doing photoshoots in Durdle Door and Lulworth Cove is allowed or requires payment and permission.

We are travelling in the UK and wanted to do our engagement photoshoot in these places. At the moment, we aren't sure if these are just landscapes open to general public or protected by some authority (requiring payment).

Answer (score 6):

Lulworth Cove and Durdle Door are part of the Lulworth Estate.
They can be contacted using [this online form](https://www.lulworth.com/the-estate/contact-us/).

I have been there several times myself and although they charge for carparking I have never been charged or challenged about taking photographs. But that's as a private tourist a professional shoot might need permission, in particular as it might mean excluding other visitors for a short time.